# Tensorflow variable images size within single batch

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am currently implementing FCN in tensorflow that enables variable input image size.

I have images of really various image sizes, but unfortunately I am not able to start the training with batch size different than 1.

I am using the feed dict in a following way:

```
feed_dict = {fcn.images: image_batch,
             fcn.labels: labels_batch,
             fcn.dropout_keep: dropout}
result = sess.run(list(tf_ops), feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I have already tried:

1. Creating `image_batch` and `labels_batch` as numpy array, this however does not work since numpy arrays does not support variable certain dimensions.
2. Creating `image_batch` and `labels_batch` as list of numpy arrays. Here seems that tensorflow is trying to call `numpy.array(image_batch)`.
3. Going with `tf.pack()`, this unfortunately does not support different image sizes as well

My question is:
Is there a way how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and advices.

Comment: There is no way to have different input sizes. TensorFlow is **not able** to apply standard operations (convolutions, fully connected layers...) on a batch of inputs of different sizes (because it cannot be an array and has to be a list).

Comment: You have to pad or resize all your images to the same size before batching them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I guess that in my case when I'm doing the semantic segmentation only cropping the images to smaller ones makes sense.

Comment: It does indeed. At test time, you can then split the image into multiple patches and then recombine them.

Answer (score 2):

So we can close this - quoting Olivier Moindrot above:

> You have to pad or resize all your images to the same size before batching them.

Note that after Olivier's answer, there was a new [`tf.image.decode_and_crop_jpeg`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_and_crop_jpeg) op added that can make it a bit easier to do this.